# illustarte an removed sentence by ulem

Tags: ulem

For a one-column text, the below command can help us to cross a sentence with a line.

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\soutthick}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{1.3pt}%
\sout{\textcolor{folly}{#1}}%
}
```

But when we have a two-column text this command does not work. How can I remove this problem?